# Simultaneously read data from serial port using Multithreading or Multiprocesing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, pyserial

I am able to read the data from serial port in python using Pyserial. But I want to read the data on multiple threads(or multiple process) so that I can read the serial data simultaneously on both the threads. I have tried to achieve this, But the problem is that the data is distorted, i.e, Half of the line comes in the first thread and other half in the second. I want to read the whole line in both threads simultaneously. How can I achieve this?

Edit:
The reason I am doing this is that I am getting serial data from a board that gives me a x value. This x value will be passed from thread(A) to the other thread(B) as a argument and the Thread B will give the sum of x and the reading that is being received in the serial while thread A will keep on updating the value of x.This process should run concurrently or in parallel. I can't explain in much detail, But this is basically the process.

Comment: Reading data from one `serial` port can not read simultaneously. [Edit] your question and explain in detail why you need to do so.

Comment: Sounds like you need a queue.

Comment: @rustyx I don't understand it quite, Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Only one thread reads the serial data, puts it in a queue and the other thread can take the data from there.